# How to set up a 2 way repeated measures ANCOVA using R?

Tags: r, anova

I have not seen an example of this particular test being done in many forums I have been scouring using R. I have seen an example of a 1 way ANCOVA [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51780/how-to-perform-an-ancova-in-r) or 2 way ANOVA (repeated measures) [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/two-way-anova-with-repeated-measures/). I have presented here my version of it after jumping through several hoops and I am not sure if it is correct.

I am trying to setup a statistical test for results from a clinical trial. A simplified version of the study is as follows. In this study I have divided my subjects into two groups (Condition A & B) with n=3 subjects per group. Dependent variable (DV) was measured in these subjects over 4 time points. I aim to conduct a two way ANCOVA (repeated measures). To ask the questions:- is the Response variable (DV) affected by the Condition-timepoint interaction with bodywt as a covariate.

*Note*: I have to stick to "traditional" `aov` function and not `lme` or `lmer` since my reports will be compared to SPSS generated output-- see [discussion here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14088/why-do-lme-and-aov-return-different-results-for-repeated-measures-anova-in-r) that `aov` and `lme` are not the same.

My example code:

```
SubjectID <- rep(1:6, each= 4) 
Condition <- c(rep('A',12),rep('B',12))
bodywt <-  rep(16:20, each= 4) 
timepoint <- rep(1:4, 6)
DV <- c(42,51,63,57,46,60,63,61,41,55,62,57,73,56,53,58,50,60,56,54,52,57,54,54)

data <- data.frame(SubjectID = SubjectID,
Condition = Condition,
bodywt = bodywt,
timepoint = timepoint,
DV = DV)

#Setting up my 2 way ANCOVA repeated measures 

stat_result <- aov(DV~Condition*timepoint + bodywt:Condition + Error(SubjectID), data)
summary(stat_result)


#Error: SubjectID
#          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#Condition  1 0.8036  0.8036
#
#Error: Within
#                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(    #F)   
#Condition            1   41.8    41.8   1.341 0.26282   
#timepoint            1  126.1   126.1   4.045 0.06042 . 
#Condition:timepoint  1  323.4   323.4  10.377 0.00501 **
#Condition:bodywt     2   81.7    40.9   1.311 0.29540   
#Residuals           17  529.8    31.2                   
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I know that I am on the right track because when I remove the covariate `bodywt`, I Notice that the `F` value and `Pr(F)` for `Condition:timepoint` are predictably affected.

```
stat_result <- aov(DV~Condition*timepoint + bodywt + Error(SubjectID), data)

summary(stat_result)

#Error: SubjectID
#          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#Condition  1 0.8036  0.8036
#
#Error: Within
#                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(    #F)   
#Condition            1   41.8    41.8   1.231 0.28175   
#timepoint            1  126.1   126.1   3.714 0.06989 . 
#bodywt               1    0.5     0.5   0.015 0.90435   
#Condition:timepoint  1  323.4   323.4   9.527 0.00636 **
#Residuals           18  611.0    33.9                   
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My question is that:

1. Is my code the correct way to set up a 2 way repeated measures ANCOVA?
2. (bonus question) What would be a best post hoc test to compare means between the two groups. Again I would prefer staying away from lme or lmer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if you'd have better luck at cross validated with this question? Definitely the bonus question is better there, but off topic for SO. Consider migrating it if you don't get answers here.

Comment: @dww I think that it might help. Let me do that.